# I'm still new to C and I dont have a clue why my float result is random (maybe type promotion rules?)

Tags: c, floating-point, type-conversion, type-promotion

I believe that it has something to do with type promotion rules, but I'm not sure and considering the fact that I'm still new to programming, I cant imagine why this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    float result;
    result = function(2.4, 4.9);

    printf("Test: %.2f\n", result);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

float function(float value1, float value2) {
    float calculation = value1 * value2;
    return calculation;
}
```

would print out

> Test: -858993472.00

I'm typing in float values and I want my calculation to return an other float value as my result, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need the function prototype above `main`. And compile with warnings, please.

Comment: Look up "forward declaration". If you are new to the language (especially for C or C++), it is a very important concept.

Comment: You're using a compiler that either uses the obsolete **28** year old C standard revision that was cancelled and replaced 18 years ago, or you're not reading the compiler warnings (which you should consider as **errors** and diligently copy into your question!).

Comment: Yes, thats actually a thing I could have done, sorry I'm in my first weeks learning C and totally forgot such an important rule.

Comment: And at first start with google and the diagnostics message!

Comment: @Antii Haapala That's a thing I considered doing before, however I thought my question had to do something with type promotion rules so after a longer time searching the web I thought posting a question would finally help me, and it did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the function before you invoke it. Here you need to put the definition above `main()` or just put a declaration before `main`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float function(float value1, float value2) {
    float calculation = value1 * value2;
    return calculation;
}
int main() {

    float result;
    result = function(2.4, 4.9);

    printf("Test: %.2f\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Or

```
#include <stdio.h>

float function(float value1, float value2);
int main() {

    float result;
    result = function(2.4, 4.9);

    printf("Test: %.2f\n", result);

    return 0;
}
float function(float value1, float value2) {
    float calculation = value1 * value2;
    return calculation;
}
```

Also if you have turned on the warning then you will possibly see a message like this

`..: 'function' was not declared in this scope`

Comment: This should include an explanation ("implicit int")

Comment: @FelixPalmen.: Oh ok

Comment: Nevermind, the dupe has it ;)

Comment: JESUS what a rookie mistake, thank you.

Comment: @FelixPalmen.: So fast ...

Comment: It should say declare your function before you **invoke** it, or use the symbol.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala.: Symbol?

Comment: well, you know, the identifier. You're not *"declaring it before defining it"* in the code above

Comment: @AnttiHaapala.: So yes...either you put the def before you invoke or put the declaration before callign point and privde the definitio somewhere

Comment: @AnttiHaapala.: Yes modified...invoked ofcourse..What use it has if they dont declare it before they invoke it...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala.: Please Check once. I hope wordings are precise now?

Comment: Yea better now.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala.: Not accurate? :)